# Unable to de-localize decimal value in form

Tags: django

I have a form input `price`. As you'd expect, it's a decimal, and the `<input type="number">` doesn't enjoy wide cross-browser compatibility with using `,` as a decimal separator character.

```
price = forms.DecimalField(
    label=_("Price"),
    required=True,
    localize=False, # prevent displaying decimal place as ','
    widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
        'step': 0.01,
        'min': 0,
        "class":"form-control",
        "placeholder": _("Two decimal places"),
    }))
```

Specifically, when rendering this field's value `{{form.price.value}}` in an update view, if the server returns a price of `20,00` nothing will be displayed in the widget. I hence tries to use the `localize` kwarg to the field as per [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms). This isn't working though; the server is still sending through a localized separator and the page doesn't work with most European languages. Here's what renders:

```
<input
  step="0.01"
  min="0"
  class="form-control"
  id="id_price"
  name="price"
  placeholder="Deux décimales"
  required=""
  value="20,00"
  type="number" >
```

Why does this occur and how do I fix this problem?

Edit: Explicitly using the [`unlocalize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#std:templatefilter-unlocalize) filter works, but doesn't explain why the kwarg variant doesn't when trying to render `{{form.price.value}}`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `floatformat` filter?

Comment: `floatformat` determines how many decimal places, not what character is used to mark the decimal separator.

Comment: You can simply create a templatetag that format the value as a standard floating point number.
You may just have the templatetag return something like: `float(value.replace(',', ''))`